# The separability of a normed space

Tags: functional-analysis

The following is an exercise of conway's Functional Analysis in page 73.

Let $\|\cdot\|$ denote the norm on each $X_i$. For $1 \leqslant p<\infty$, define
$$
\oplus_p X_i \equiv\left\{x \in \prod_i X_i:\|x\| \equiv\left[\sum_i\|x(i)\|^p\right]^{1 / p}<\infty\right\} .
$$
Show that $\oplus_{p} X_i$ is separable iff $I$ is countable and each $X_i$ is separable.

I can prove that when $\oplus_p X_i$ is separable, then $I$ is countable and each $X_i$ is separable. (For if $\oplus_p X_i$ is separable, then $\oplus_p X_i/\ker P_i$ is separable, where $P_i$ is the projection, then $X_i\cong\oplus_p X_i/\ker P_i$ is separable, while $I$'s countability is obvious ).

However, if $I$ is countable and each $X_i$ is separable, I can not prove $\oplus_{p} X_i$ is separable.

Can anyone give some hints? Thanks for your help.

Comment: WLOG assume that $I \subseteq \mathbb{N}$. Let $\{x_j^i: j \in \mathbb{N}\}$ be a countable dense subset of $X_i$. Show that $\{ (x_{j_1}^1, \dots, x_{j_n}^n, 0, 0, \dots): n \in \mathbb{N}, j_1, \dots, j_n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a countable dense subset of $\bigoplus_p X_i$.

Comment: Thanks！I get the point.